# How to check for an Empty Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, null

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 (C#) web app, and in it I have a gridview that gets its data from an oracle database.

I want to know how to check if the gridview is empty, and the do something.

I have already tried:

```
if(GridView.Rows.Count == 0)
{
// Do Something
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your code *should* work.  But only after GridView.DataBind() has been called.  Generally I don't check the GridView it's self, but the datasource of the grid view.

```
DataTable data = DAL.getdata();
if (data.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    ShowEmptyData();
}
else
{
    Grid.DataSource = dt;
    Grid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This doesn't work since the `GridView` is data bound and is going to fetch the actual data at a later time while rendering the page. You should check this by directly querying the data binding source of the gridview (see if the actual list that's grid view bound to is empty or not).

If you just want to display something when it's empty, you should use `<EmptyDataTemplate>` in your markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
<EmptyDataTemplate>The grid is empty</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the other responses. I want to add little information, you should get rows.count after databind method :

```
int rowCount = GridView.Rows.Count; // returns zero

GridView.DataBind();

rowCount = GridView.Rows.Count; // returns actual row count
```

Comment: Just a little more info: the gridview will show only the max number of rows for paging if paging is enabled. So it is best to check the actual datasource

Comment: Hi @Canavar, just wanted to know if 
GridView.DataBind(); is possible without binding to any datasource ?

Comment: Checking the row count can still be an issue if the EmptyDataTemplate is used and there are row built into the result. It is common to add a Footer with Insert operations for a new records when no data is returned, adjustments for these rows need to be made when checking row count.

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ yes. Use ViewState[] after bidning the GV to a DataTable and reuse the viewstate when you need to back to the GV. Google it. It's been discussed many times.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using databinding, the the row count of the datasource not the count on the grid itself.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy: Hope it works for you.. :)

Use event of GridView DataBound: which fires after data is bound.

```
 protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;

     if (rowCount == 0)
     {
         GridView1.Visible = false;                
     }
     else
     {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Not quite. Row.Count includes any headers and footers

Answer (score 1):

First create a helper class.

```
public static class GridViewExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<GridViewRow> AsEnumerable(this GridView grid)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            yield return row;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsEmpty(this GridView grid)
    {
        return !grid.AsEnumerable().Any(t => t.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow);
    }
}
```

Then just call IsEmpty

```
GridView1.IsEmpty()
```

Comment: Any chance you could rewrite this for VS2005?

Answer (score 0):

In case you've configured your GV to automatically fetch the data from DB, then you may add the following line as the first statement of your GV in Source mode:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>No data found.</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

And then continue with the normal code in your GV.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers already, `GridView.Rows.Count` is not enough on its own, depending on the nature of your `GridView`, especially if it's a dynamic gv, which in most cases it is, plus you have to factor in `Paginating`, Headers and Footers, which alter the row count.

I use a simple method to tell me ...

```
//checks if a gridview has any actual rows of data (not just blank rows filled in by the Load
protected bool gvNoData(GridView gv)
{
    int wsDataRow = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gv.Rows)
        if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)gvRow.FindControl("hfStudentID");
            if (hf != null)
                if (hf.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                    wsDataRow +=1;
        }

    //if a count was generated then there are data rows, otherwise the rows are blank or nonexistant
    if (wsDataRow > 0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

So running something like this will tell you if the Rows are really "
"DATA" rows, or empty or nothing!

Obviously in my case I have a HiddenField to tell me if the GridViewRow is an actual data row, as I prefill my gridview with blank rows (for my purposes) and some datarows.

However, a simpler version to check based on DataRow vs HeaderRow, etc...

```
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in myGridView.Rows)
            if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
//do what you need
            }
```

I hope this helps.

In short, there is no GridView.IsEmpty() function unfortunately, unless you enumerate one as shown below.