# How to check grid view is empty or not

Tags: asp.net

How to check for grid view empty or not please let me know

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for an Empty Gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731461/how-to-check-for-an-empty-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid1.Rows.Count` shows the total number of records in a page assuming `Grid1` is the `ID` of datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy: Hope it works for you.. :)

Use event of GridView DataBound: which fires after data is bound.

```
 protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;

     if (rowCount == 0)
     {
         GridView1.Visible = false;                
     }
     else
     {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
     }

 }
```